# GCP has suspended my machine and says I'm mining cryptocurrency. How do I fix the issue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP suspended my instance on the pretext of mining cryptocurrency on the 3rd of August 2020. In fact, my instance has not been reinstated yet, and I am writing to seek help on the matter.

Details of my instance are:

Machine Type: n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory)
Zone: us-west1-b
Last used on: 3rd August 2020

The two questions I have:
1. How do I get my instance reinstated along with its project files? I have submitted an appeal for the same, however, have not received a response.
2. What was the issue with my instance? 
3. What measures should I take to avoid this situation in the future?

I came across this article on Stack Overflow [Google banned the project believing that it has cryptocurrency mining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713699/google-banned-the-project-believing-that-it-has-cryptocurrency-mining) detailing a similar issue but it has no responses.

For further context, this was the email I received from GCP:

We’ve detected that your Google Cloud Project (project id) IP (address not disclosed) is violating the Supplemental Terms and Conditions For Google Cloud Startup Program by engaging cryptocurrency mining, resulting in the suspension of all project resources displaying this behavior.

Abuse Details:

Origin: (project id) / (IP address not disclosed)
Time frame: 2020-08-03 01:35 to 2020-08-03 01:42 (Pacific Time)

Requesting you to help me out with this.

Comment: You will need to create a new instance. I hope you have a backup or documentation on how to rebuild your instance. Since your instance appears to have been hacked, there is little chance that you can reinstate it. Since a hacked VM instance could have had extensive roles by default to your project, I would delete the entire project and start over. For the new project spend time to tighten up your security so you are not hacked again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, StackOverflow community can do nothing with such cases, you should wait for response from Google Cloud Support and follow the instructions.

Have a look at the documentation [Google Cloud project suspension](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines#gcp_project_suspension):

> Google Cloud projects may be suspended due to violations of the GCP
> ToS, including the Google Cloud Acceptable Use Policy (GCP AUP). When
> activities that violate the Google Cloud AUP or ToS are detected in a
> project, the project owner has an obligation to fix the violation
> immediately. If the violation is not fixed, Google may take action to
> suspend the project.

and

> To recover a suspended project please fix the issue and follow the
> link in the notification email or contact [Google support](https://support.google.com/accounts/contact/disabled2). See the
> [Policy Violations FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7002354?hl=en) for more information on appeal best practices in
> case of a Project resource suspension.

More information you can find at [Policy Violations FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7002354?hl=en):

> *What are the best practices for ensuring that my projects are not taken down for abusive activity?* Here are some of the best practices
> for appealing a warning or avoiding a suspension:
>
> - Monitor the relevant email address (the project owner email address) regularly so that you know as soon as your project is warned.
> - Make sure that emails from google-cloud-compliance@google.com do not go to the spam folder.
> - Fix the issue as soon as possible. Your email will tell you how you can fix the issue. You have a limited time window to fix the issue as
>   described in the email.
> - Ensure that your project does not violate the Google Cloud Platform [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms/) or [Acceptable Use Policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup).
> - Respond to the notification as described above in [My project has received a warning. What should I do now?](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7002354?hl=en#warning-to-do). (Please do not respond
>   to the email.) Let us know the steps you've taken to fix the issue.
>   Explain clearly and concisely. Our team needs to know the steps you
>   took to fix the issue, but we don't need to know the exact code you
>   used.
> - If you need help fixing the issue, you can contact support from the Google Cloud Platform Support page.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar suspension from GCP where my container was not even related to mining.

Figured out later that when I was trying to configure my postgres config file, I configured it such that it accepts any connection from any machine ( bad practice ).
It was development mode, but google flagged it as suspicious and suspended the Virtual Instance.

Therefore I would say for this sort of warning, its best to see the logs to figure out the main cause of the error.